# Fastest way to read a large XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, data-mining, information-retrieval

I'm working on a java project to optimize existing code. Currently i'm using BufferedReader/FileInputStream to read content of an XML file as String in Java.

But my question is , is there any faster way to read XML content.Are SAX/DOM faster than BufferedReader/FileInputStream?

Need help regarding the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean...  reading the file with with BufferedReader/FileInputStream will get you the bytes, but not as an XML document...    SAX/DOM parses will both read the file, and then parse the XML into a more useful structure.  Generally SAX parsers are faster than DOM parsers.

Comment: Is this part of the application considered a bottleneck after stressing the app and using a profiler? If yes, then instead of read the XML file as a String and then parse it, I guess it would be better to use a SAX parser since it's faster than DOM.

Comment: I mean using BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) .where filename is XML file and b has entire xml file data.Now i parse the data line by line and extract specific fields and print it.

Comment: I'm looking for fastest way to parse an xml document and should be faster than using BufferedReader. Please help in this regard

Comment: @Mohana Nothing will be *faster* than reading the raw stream, unless of course *your* parsing code is slow, and you didn't post that code, so how could we say? --- Now, reading and parsing XML yourself is ..... *questionable*. Does your code handle all the quirks correctly? Better use a built-in parser, e.g. SAX or StAX, but not DOM since you'd run out of memory on large XML files.

Comment: There's no point in parsing an XML document unless you are doing something with the data, and in many applications, the "doing something" is the bottleneck. But before you can do something with the data, you need to read the file of disk and parse it. Parsing it is a bigger task than reading it off the disk, so why are you so focussed on the task of reading it?

Answer (score 8):

I think that your code shown in other question is faster than DOM-like parsers which would definitely require more memory and likely some computation in order to reconstruct the document in full. You may want to profile the code though.

I also think that your code can be prettified a bit for streaming processing if you would use javax `XMLStreamReader`, which I found quite helpful for many tasks. That class is *"... is designed to be the lowest level and most efficient way to read XML data", [according to Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html)*.

Here is the excerpt from my code where I parse StackOverflow users XML file distributed as a public data dump:

```
// the input file location
private static final String fileLocation = "/media/My Book/Stack/users.xml";

// the target elements
private static final String USERS_ELEMENT = "users";
private static final String ROW_ELEMENT = "row";

// get the XML file handler
//
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
    fileInputStream);

// reading the data
//
while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {

  int eventCode = xmlStreamReader.next();

  // this triggers _users records_ logic
  //
  if ((XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT == eventCode)
      && xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(USERS_ELEMENT)) {

    // read and parse the user data rows
    //
    while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {

      eventCode = xmlStreamReader.next();

      // this breaks _users record_ reading logic
      //
      if ((XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT == eventCode)
          && xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(USERS_ELEMENT)) {
        break;
      }
      else {

        if ((XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT == eventCode)
            && xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(ROW_ELEMENT)) {

          // extract the user data
          //
          User user = new User();
          int attributesCount = xmlStreamReader.getAttributeCount();
          for (int i = 0; i < attributesCount; i++) {
            user.setAttribute(xmlStreamReader.getAttributeLocalName(i),
                xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(i));
          }
          // all other user record-related logic
          //

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That users file format is quite simple and similar to your `Bank.xml` file:

```
<users>
  <row Id="1567200" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2012-07-31T23:57:57.770" DisplayName="XXX" EmailHash="XXX" LastAccessDate="2012-08-01T00:55:12.953" Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" />
  ...
</users>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different parser options available.

Consider using a *streaming* parser, because the DOM may become quite big. I.e. either a push or a pull parser.

It's not as if XML parsers are necessarily slow. Consider your web browser. It does XML parsing all the time, and tries really hard to be robust to syntax errors. Usually, memory is the bigger issue.